# Load images from API

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, moltin

I'm creating an e-commerce app with (Moltin.com) SDK, I set every thing well as it shown in the documentation but now I need to load multi images of single product in table view with custom cell, I set the shown code below and all I can get is a single image my app ignore load the other images view controller code is

```
class vc: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var productDict:NSDictionary?

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
fileprivate let MY_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER = "MyCell"
fileprivate var productImages:NSArray?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self



     Moltin.sharedInstance().product.listing(withParameters: productDict!.value(forKeyPath: "url.https") as! [String : Any]!, success: { (response) -> Void in
        self.productImages = response?["result"] as? NSArray
        self.tableview?.reloadData()
    }) { (response, error) -> Void in

        print("Something went wrong...")
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if productImages != nil {
        return productImages!.count
    }

    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MY_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    let row = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
    let collectionDictionary = productImages?.object(at: row) as! NSDictionary
    cell.setCollectionDictionary(collectionDictionary)
    return cell
}
```

and my custom cell code is

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

func setCollectionDictionary(_ dict: NSDictionary) {
    // Set up the cell based on the values of the dictionary that we've been passed


    // Extract image URL and set that too...
    var imageUrl = ""

    if let images = dict.value(forKey: "images") as? NSArray {
        if (images.firstObject != nil) {
            imageUrl = (images.firstObject as! NSDictionary).value(forKeyPath: "url.https") as! String
        }
    }

    myImage?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl))


}
```

Can anyone show me where is the issue that doesn't let me get all the images of my product?
I'm using SWIFT 3, with XCode

Comment: Your question is not clear , You want to display multiple images in cell ? , but where are imageView ? , and you are  getting `(images.firstObject as! NSDictionary` then how you can achieve this ?

Comment: @MikeAlter, you can see that I'm calling the image view in the cell for row in my function (set collection dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

In the code below you are always getting one URL from images array (firstObject).

```
if let images = dict.value(forKey: "images") as? NSArray {
    if (images.firstObject != nil) {
        imageUrl = (images.firstObject as! NSDictionary).value(forKeyPath: "url.https") as! String
    }
}

myImage?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl))
```

If I understand correctly you should get every image in images array by the indexPath.row of your tableView.

For example add new parameter to method like this:

```
func setCollection(with dict: NSDictionary, and index: Int) {
// Set up the cell based on the values of the dictionary that we've been passed


// Extract image URL and set that too...
var imageUrlString = ""

if let images = dict.value(forKey: "images") as? Array<NSDictionary>, images.count >= index {
    guard let lImageUrlString = images[index]["url.https"] else { return }
    imageUrlString = lImageUrlString
}

guard let imageURL = URL(string: imageUrl) else { return }
myImage?.sd_setImage(with: imageURL)

}
```

Than when call this method in cellForRow just add indexPath.row to the second param.
But if you want show multiple images in one cell you should add more imageViews to the custom cell or use UICollectionView. 
Just ping me if I don't understand you clear.

Comment: I'm Happy for your response my code inside the MyCell is working well because I'm using the same function to load my collections and products inside my app, I think the problem in the calling this line of code  `       {{{ .     Moltin.sharedInstance().product.listing(withParameters: productDict!.value(forKeyPath: "url.https") as! [String : Any]!, success: { (response) -> Void in
        self.productImages = response?["result"] as? NSArray
        self.tableview?.reloadData()
    }) { (response, error) -> Void in

        print("Something went wrong...")
    }`}}}}}